# Compare 2 strings and get match - T SQL

Tags: t-sql, compare

What i want is to compare 2 strings and get how many characters both strings have in common.

For example:

- I have declare a variable with value `Test1`.
- Get values from a table with a select query and compare them with the variable to get how many characters are the same in order starting from the first character of the variable.
- I compare the variable against the values from the query.
- Character are case sensitive (i use `UPPER( string )` to capitalize both variable and value from the select statement)
- I will select the String with the `MAX()` number. From the output image i will select `Test1` and NOT `Test11` because `Test11` exist the number of characters against the variable.

**Output**

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: 1. Please [edit] your question to include [proper sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and desired results. Also include your current code. 2. Does the location of the chars within the strings matter? I mean, when comparing `Zohar` with `Zorah` - do you consider that as 3 chars match or as 5 chars match? What about case sensitivity? Do you consider`z` as equals to `Z`?

Comment: Adding zu Zohar: What about duplicates? e.g. "Zorro" and "Zohar" - how many common characters are there? Please provide sample data and the expected output. Just a general hint: T-SQL is very poor if used as string engine...

Comment: i will upload all i have done included sample data in a while. thanks in advance.

Comment: @ZoharPeled question update.

Comment: 6th row (`cest`) has a three chars match to `Test1` yet your results show 0. Why is that?

Comment: The comparison starts from the beginning. Variable first later is `T` and cest is `c` so the counter remain 0 and stops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE for this...

For your next question: Please to not post pictures. Rather try to set up a *stand alone* and *self-running* sample as I do it here (DDL and INSERT).

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('Test1')
                       ,('Test11')
                       ,('Test')
                       ,('abc')
                       ,('Tyes')
                       ,('cest');
```

--This is the string we use to compare (casing depends on the underlying collation)

```
DECLARE @CheckString VARCHAR(100)='Test1';
```

--The query

```
WITH recCTE AS
(
SELECT t.ID
      ,t.SomeValue
      ,1 AS pos
      --,SUBSTRING(@CheckString,1,1) AS LetterInCheckString
      --,SUBSTRING(t.SomeValue,1,1) AS LetterInTableValue
      ,CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@CheckString,1,1)=SUBSTRING(t.SomeValue,1,1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsTheSame
FROM @tbl t

UNION ALL

SELECT recCTE.ID
      ,recCTE.SomeValue
      ,recCTE.Pos+1
      --,SUBSTRING(@CheckString,recCTE.Pos+1,1) 
      --,SUBSTRING(recCTE.SomeValue,recCTE.Pos+1,1) 
      ,CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(@CheckString,recCTE.Pos+1,1)=SUBSTRING(recCTE.SomeValue,recCTE.Pos+1,1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
FROM recCTE
WHERE recCTE.IsTheSame=1 AND SUBSTRING(@CheckString,recCTE.Pos+1,1) <>''
)
SELECT ID,SomeValue,SUM(IsTheSame)
FROM recCTE
GROUP BY ID,SomeValue
ORDER BY ID;
```

The idea in short:

- We start with the *recursion's anchor* at position=1
- We add to this, as long as the string is the same and `substring()` returns a value.
- The result is the `SUM()` of same characters.

To be honest: T-SQL is the wrong tool for this...

Comment: Nice! I was starting to work on a solution based on [Alan Burstein's N-Grams](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams) but checking the char match one by one is probably best handled using a recursive cte. +1

Comment: @ZoharPeled My first idea was a tally table with a computed `TOP` clause and `CROSS APPLY` this to the table. This would allow for an easy, position-safe comparison of characters. But then I read your comment about `cest` and the OP's answer :-)

Comment: Thanks all of them for your support. Appreciated. i will check the answer and provide my feedeback!

Comment: @Shnugo seems that the output is correct! if you have time please provide a more detailed explanation due to the fact that i m new on that field. What do you propouse instead of T-SQL (all data are stored in SQL server)?

Comment: @Error1004, If T-SQL is a good choice will depend on the amount of data. Any *real* programming language will deal with this better. The concept *recursive CTE* is described and explained were well, just search for this... The idea is to start with a SELECT and use UNION ALL to add rows to this set with a *hidden RBAR*. If you need more details, just come back, best with a new question on a specific issue.

Comment: i search about it and get the actual point, Initial with 1 and add on this using `UNION ALL`. in case of any questions i will come back. Thanks a lot